# Javascript history convert to php line

Tags: javascript, php

Hello so I have this code

```
echo "<script>alert('Message is too short.');location.href='index.php';</script>";
```

that will show alert message and will redirect to the index page. But I want to change.
`location.href='index.php';` to `javascript:history.go(-1)`

The thing is I don't want to get the textbox cleared by redirecting back to the previous page.

Comment: Why not use `sessions` or `cookies` ?

Comment: You need any example to implement it ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen yes please :)

Comment: You want to do in `javascript` or `php` ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen can you do both so I can pick which is better?

Comment: use this and check window.location.href='javascript:history.go(-1)';

Comment: @FewFlyBy can i put this in answer.

Comment: @satishrajak yes you can please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to redirect to previous page inside your script tag

```
window.location.href='javascript:history.go(-1)';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example in php

**index.php** (The first file)

```
<a href='second.php'>Second </a>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['value']))
{
echo $_SESSION['value'];
}
?>
```

**second.php** (The second file)

```
 <a href='<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>'>Previous </a>
 <?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["value"] = "YourName";
 ?>
```

What i am doing is just having a link to second file, And in the second i am making the anchor to point `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` which is the previous link and i am starting a session and putting a value into `$_SESSION['value']`

Then when users click it again back in the first page, i am starting the session and checking whether it has the value for `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` and if so i am printing the value of it.